# Regex to detect Python Dictionary Syntax

Tags: python, regex

I've been struggling and my head is about to explode. So I need to write a basic Regex script in Python that will identify if a string has the format (pattern) of a Python dictionary. With the code below, I've only managed to successfully match when the string is like this: `my_dict = {1: 'apple', 2: 'ball'}`

I would like to match something like the below which doesn't only use numbers as keys and alphabets as values:

```
{
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
```

---------------Dictionary Detector-------------------

```
# importing regex module
import re

# printing script purpose
# `\n` is for printing newline
print('\nScript designed to detect whether if user input is a Python dictionary construction.\n')

# getting user input
user_inp = input('Type Text> ')

if user_inp != '{}':
    user_inp = user_inp.replace('}', ',}', 1)

if re.search('''^{((('(\w|\d)*')|(\w|\d)*) *: * (('(\w|\d)*')|(\w|\d)*) *, *)*}$''', user_inp):
    print('yes, a dictionary has been detected.')

else:
    print('No dictionary has been detected.')
```

Comment: Can JSON help you with that? `import json; data = json.loads(user_inp); if isinstance(data, dict): ...`

Comment: Are you interested in a regex that would cover recursive dictionaries, such as "text = "{1:{2:3}}"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `json` might be a better fit, but if you still want to do it with regex, here is one:

```
dict_reg = re.compile(r"""
\s*                 # user might leave spaces in front
{                   # the opening curly of dict
(                   # the key-value pair groups begin
\s*                 # user might leave a space
[\"'().,\w]+        # the "key" part: matches strings, tuples, numbers and variables
\s*:\s*             # the colon and possible spaces around
[\"'()\[\].,\w]+    # the "value" part: matches strings, tuples, lists, numbers and variables
\s*                 # again, user might leave a space after writing value
,?                  # the comma that seperates key-value pairs (optional, last one may not have it)
\s*                 # again, user might leave a space
)*                  # the key-value pair groups as many as possible (* implies empty dict is also ok)
}                   # the closing curly of dict
\s*                 # again, user might leave a space because why not
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

You can use as:

```
re.fullmatch(dict_reg, user_inp)
```

The apparent cases it does not match:

arithmetic expressions e.g. `2+5` as keys or values

`dict`s as values

nested dicts

and possibly many more. But it should do okay for basic dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're a lifesaver! It worked when the dictionary is listed one a single line. Where would we add `\n*` for possible new lines in user input?

Comment: @MohammedHoorzook, I think the function `input` cannot return a new line i.e. when user presses enter, the input taking process is over and that new line is stripped. But even you supply a string yourself that contains new lines, thanks to `\s*` in the regex, there will be a match. I wrote "user might leave a space" as comments in regex and those account for the newlines, too.

Comment: Thank you @MustafaAydin. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a regex solution, but if you are using python, you can do:

```
def is_dictionary(string) -> bool:
        if type(eval(string)) is dict:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```